# ESLint with React gives `declare only React component per file` errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I've setup eslint & eslint-plugin-react.

When I run ESLint, the linter returns declare only React component per file errors, for next function.

```
export function parseList(message, id, ulClasses = '', liClasses = '') {
  const mdlist = regexMap.MARKDOWN_LIST;
  const list = message.match(mdlist);
  const sanitize = DOMPurify.sanitize;

  list.forEach((listItem, i) => {
    listItem = listItem.replace('*', '');
    message = message.replace(list[i], `<li><p class=${liClasses}>${listItem}</p></li>`);
  });

  return React.createElement('ul', {
    className: ulClasses,
    id: id,
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
      __html: sanitize(message),
    },
  });
}
```

any idea how to fix that in the above function without disabling eslint